# How to watermark/overlay image on an html page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to somehow watermark an html page with a semi-transparent image that still lets through user interaction on the page behind it?  Contradictory, and doesn't seem possible without some complicated scripting, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I think you don't understand what a watermark is.  A watermark is typically BEHIND everything, and only on the background of the page.  Do you mean you want a transparent OVERLAY that allows interaction?

Comment: Although `@Aaron's` answer is really good, I don't see the point of watermarking HTML page when even a slightly knowledgeable user can fire up dev console and simply remove it....

Comment: Correct, @Mystere Man, I do actually mean overlay.  I'll see if I can edit the title to correct this.

Answer (score 8):

This will work for most modern browsers:

```
div#watermark {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
    background: url('path/to/image.png') center center no-repeat;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Unfortunately, IE doesn't recognize the `pointer-events` property, so you need to use a javascript fallback [like this one](http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/) if needed. Also, some older mobile browsers/old IE don't support `position: fixed`, so that'll also require another javascript fallback to position the image in the center of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#watermark {
  background-image: url('watermark.png');
  repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 50;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  float: left;
}
```